Use SQL to pick up numbering where previously left off
I have a table like this:
series
item
All names in the series inherit the series name plus a sequential numbering appended to the end. e.g.
-------|---------
series | item
-------|---------
 xxx   | xxx001
 xxx   | xxx002
 xxx   | xxx003

In a temporary table I have new items that i need to add to the inventory.
-------|---------
series | item
-------|---------
 xxx   | xxx
 xxx   | xxx
 xxx   | xxx
 xxx   | xxx

I need to have the numbering pickup where we previuosly left off. So if I add these four items to the permanent table I need them to look like this:
-------|---------
series | item
-------|---------
 xxx   | xxx004
 xxx   | xxx005
 xxx   | xxx006
 xxx   | xxx007

All suggestions are appreciated.
I have been able to get a substring of the MAX item in each series which gives me the latest number.  I can add 1 to that number to add the number to the temp table but in the cases where I'm adding more than one item to a series, they all get the same number.
xxx  | xxx004
xxx  | xxx004
xxx  | xxx004
xxx  | xxx004


Why can't you use an auto_increment?  Why do you have a temporary table?  Instead of hand waving the details you should provide a [mre] with a schema and example values, and the expected result.

Do you need all the rows from the table inserted as a single transaction?  If so you could use a variable.  Otherwise process a row at a time and it will pick up the new max.

Have you tried row_number()?

Also, if xxx is not part of the sequence number consider 1st normal form and splitting that column into two.

Provide complete sample code according to Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

Create a subquery geting max numbers per series in temp table - including the 0 (zero) for possible new series. Join your temp table to the subquery on series and construct newly numbered items from max_item_number and Row_Number() Over() analytic function:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
  series_items ( series, item ) AS
    ( Select 'AAA', 'AAA001' Union All 
      Select 'AAA', 'AAA002' Union All 
      Select 'AAA', 'AAA003' Union All 
      Select 'BCD', 'BCD001' Union All 
      Select 'BCD', 'BCD002' Union All 
      Select 'GGG', 'GGG001' 
    ), 
  temp_tbl ( series, item ) AS 
    ( Select 'AAA', 'AAA' Union All 
      Select 'AAA', 'AAA' Union All 
      Select 'BCD', 'BCD' Union All 
      Select 'BCD', 'BCD' Union All 
      Select 'BCD', 'BCD' Union All 
      Select 'BCD', 'BCD' Union All
      Select 'FFF', 'FFF' Union All
      Select 'FFF', 'FFF' Union All
      Select 'GGG', 'GGG'
    )

--      S Q L : 
SELECT    t.series, 
          CONCAT( t.series , 
                  Lpad( x.max_item_number + Row_Number() Over(Partition By t.series), 
                        3, '0'
                       ) 
                ) as item_numbered
FROM      temp_tbl t
INNER JOIN 
        ( Select    tt.series, 
                    CAST( Coalesce( Max( Replace(si.item, tt.series, '') ), 0 ) as UNSIGNED ) as max_item_number
          From      temp_tbl tt
          Left Join series_items si ON(tt.series = si.series)
          Group By  tt.series
        ) x ON(x.series = t.series)
ORDER BY  t.item

/*    R e s u l t : 
series  item_numbered
------  -------------
AAA     AAA004
AAA     AAA005
BCD     BCD003
BCD     BCD004
BCD     BCD005
BCD     BCD006
FFF     FFF001
FFF     FFF002
GGG     GGG002      */

See the fiddle here.
